# Why fgrep? (Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm)

Tags: grep

I see there are grep and fgrep, the later uses Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm.
Can you give me a use case when I would use fgrep (grep -F), why fgrep was created?

Comment: You'd use `grep -F` when the pattern contains characters that are _special_ to regex, essentially when your input is a fixed string so as to avoid escaping those.

Answer (score 2):

### To the point:

`grep -F` does not match regular expressions, only exact/fixed strings, because of this it is faster. It is also practical to use it when you don't need regular expression syntax, so as not to bother escaping regular expression characters contained in your string.

### Sidenote:

Direct invocation of `fgrep` is deprecated. You should use `grep -F`.